# Cannot upgrade sharded mongoDB or stop the balancer

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

`mongos` is not running in the beginning. When tried to start the `mongos` I see the following log:

> Fri Mar 22 17:43:13.383 [mongosMain] ERROR: error upgrading config
>   database to v4 :: caused by :: newer version 4 of mongo config
>   metadata is required, current version is 3, need to run mongos with
>   --upgrade

But with `--upgrade` parameter, I see the following log:

> Fri Mar 22 17:43:39.273 [mongosMain] ERROR: error upgrading config
>   database to v4 :: caused by :: balancer must be stopped for config
>   upgrade

Now the problem is: I cannot stop the balancer by `sh.stopBalancer()` because I cannot start mongos. It's a deadlock to me now. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I found the the problem. I should connect to port `27019` for a `configsrv`. In this way I don't need to start `mongos`. Instead the `sh.stopBalancer()` could be executed simply in `mongo` interpreter.

Comment: Just make sure that you don't screw up the sync between the other config servers when you change data directly on one of them. Since mongos is normally in charge of doing that

Comment: You actually need to start `mongos`, since it is it that will perform the upgrade. You just don't need to have it running *during* the connection to the `configsvr`.

Comment: @rbrito There were errors preventing `mongos` from starting. In order to fix them I needed to connect to `configsrv` directly first (then I basically wiped all configs).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem just now. I updated my mongo database from verion 2.0.4 to 2.4.3.
I cannot connect to mongos because config server need to be upgraded. However, I can not stop the balancer using command stopBalancer() because my mongos is inactive. I did not find other solutions from stackoverflow. I tried many times.

My solution is:
1, ssh to the config server;

2, use config database;

maybe need to pass authentication;

3, 
run db.settings.update( { _id: "balancer" }, { $set : { stopped: true } } , true ) 
to stop balancer;

4, I can run "mongos" with --upgrade option;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you followed the recommendation to always run 3 config server, I would try these steps:

1. Make sure all other mongos clients are stopped. If no mongos are running, no balancer should be keeping a lock either.
2. If you still get the error (after being certain that no mongos are connected to the config servers) I would stop all config servers but one and clear any remains of balancer locks in the admin database. After a successful try with this config server, I would reset the other two. If it was not successful, you still have two other copies.

Comment: The wired thing is all 3 configsrv are running but all mongos clients are closed. There's still error when trying to upgrade.

Comment: But thanks for your help anyway. I rechecked how to connect to a configsrv following your hint and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was to connect to the *configsvr* with mongo shell

**mongo --host ip_of_config_server_host --port 27019**

and setting the balancer off from there with

**sh.setBalancerState(false)**

After this I could do the config server upgrade with

**mongos --port 27017 --configdb ip_of_config_server_host --upgrade**