# Unable to upgrade mongod configuration server

Tags: mongodb

After running my brand new cluster for about 6 hours. I restarted one of my mongos instances and it failed:

> ... Wed Jul 10 22:02:36.526 [mongosMain] ERROR: error upgrading config database to v4 :: caused by :: newer version 4 of mongo config metadata is required, current version is 1, need to run mongos with --upgrade

I then ran the following command:

mongos --configdb mongoconfig1.xxxxx.com:1234,mongoconfig2.xxxxx.com:1234,mongoconfig3.xxxxx.com:1234 --upgrade

Which also failed.

> ... Wed Jul 10 22:10:39.218 [mongosMain] starting upgrade of config server from v1 to v4 Wed Jul 10 22:10:39.355 [mongosMain] distributed lock 'configUpgrade/mongos2.xxxxx.com:12345:1373494238:1804289383' unlocked. Wed Jul 10 22:10:39.356 [mongosMain] ERROR: error upgrading config database to v4 :: caused by :: newer version 4 of mongo config metadata is required, current version is 1, don't know how to upgrade from this version

This error seems strange. All machines are running the latest version 2.4.5. Has anybody seen this before? Any ideas in how to resolve this?

Also seeing a lot of this:

> resetting shard version of certiorem.feeds on mongoshard3.xxxx.com:12345, version is zero

Comment: that last message is normal in a new cluster - it just means there is a sharded collection that mongos didn't have information that it was sharded before (sharded collections have versions which track their changes, 0 means unsharded collection).   So everything was running fine until you restarted one mongos server?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Yes basically. I ended up deleting all data/collections on the shards,  and configuration servers and went though the setup process again. I'm sure this wasn't necessary, however I was unable to track down the cause. Now the cluster is performing ok.

Comment: See this problem and my solutions

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576766/cannot-upgrade-sharded-mongodb-or-stop-the-balancer/27255289#27255289